# Sencha Touch: how to change the color of selectfield using css?

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2

Do we have any specified css for coloring the selecfield in sencha touch2?

My selectfield code as of now is as follows:

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    options: [
    {text: 'AI',  value: 'first'},
    {text: 'AK', value: 'second'},
    {text: 'BR',  value: 'third'}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a separate css class for your select field. Use " css: 'yourclassname' " after your "xtype" value and define the class as

```
.yourclassname{ background-color:#000;color:#fff;font:normal 12px Arial;}
```

So your code will be

```
              xtype: 'selectfield',
              cls:  'yourclassname',
              options: [
                        {text: 'AI',  value: 'first'},
                        {text: 'AK', value: 'second'},
                        {text: 'BR',  value: 'third'}
                        ]
```

thanks

Comment: HI Sudip,
I did the same thing before posting this msg. But problem is even though the selectfield's color changes to black then also the color of the dropdown arrow and some area around it is white.
ANkit

Comment: Hi Ankit, actually in sencha even it shows you a select field, but in the actual code if u inspect it, u can see some formatted div are creating the view. So u can easily select the child div through css selector and formatting your code.

Comment: HI Sudip, did not get you.. can you please explain it using a code snippet?

Comment: Inspect your code using Inspect Element in Chrome/Safari and check for the DIV structure for your select element.

Comment: .x-field {
min-height: 2.5em;
background: 
white;
}
is what i suspect.. i tried doing
.x-field {
min-height: 2.5em;
background-color:#000000;
}
in my customised css file. But still no effect. Did i track the right element? Also,, do i need to do anything like including any css class for .xfield entry in my .js file?

Comment: Option values as you defined in your sencha framework's js file, it is actually creating a DIV structure, try to grab the parent element by using any ID or CSS class name or CSS selector. Your problem will solve instantly.

Comment: if i write an entry for .x-field or any other class in my .css file then will it overwrite the entry in sencha(.css?
Also, i was not able to find d entry for changing for the above mentioned selectfield issue.

Comment: Well, .x-field will not going to overwrite your targeted element, because sencha may used the same class in other operations also. So find out the parent unique DIV ID or your specified CLASS name and overwrite your class as #yourdivid .x-field {css properties} and remember to put 'important' mark on each css value.

Answer (score 0):

Please check: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/theming

Using Sass & Compass is the right way for styling your app!

Comment: so there is no way by which we can do this only by using css?

Comment: you can but it is called "hardcode". right click on selectfield -> Inspect element. Check what classes are used for selectfield and then style them as you want.